# Debug Log in RESTResource

Tags: apex, webservices, debug

My problem is very similar to [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/61061/debug-log-not-working-with-restresource) . But adding necessary user(Site owner) to Debug Logs doesn't help me. I don't see any logs at all. But webservice works well.

Comment: Are you using a `Force.com Site`? If so this question is a duplicate of https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/1149/2995

Comment: Yes, you are right, unfortunately, I didn't notice this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the webservice / rest service is hosted as public using Sites.
I guess while calling the webservice from your client, you just need set the cookie. Something like

```
http.setHeader('Cookie', 'debug_logs=debug_logs,domain=.force.com')
```

The post Adrian linked has more details about this update. Moreover check if you can set the **Traced Entity Type** as your Rest Class and see if puts some log out.
[image]